# Slamdata join on array of ids

Tags: sql, mongodb, slamdata

I have a problem connecting two collections on SlamData. 
First collection is Worker and there's an _id field in it.
Second one is Order and there is an array of workers id's in it. 
My query isn't working:

```
SELECT worker.nazwisko,SUM(orders.odleglosc)as "suma odleglosci",SUM(orders.cena)as "suma zarobku",SUM(orders.godz)as "suma godzin" 
FROM "/test/test/Order" orders 
JOIN "/test/test/Worker" worker ON orders.pracownicy=worker._id 
GROUP BY worker.nazwisko
```

I know that this is wrong:

```
orders.pracownicy=worker._id
```

but i dont know how to fix it, i read about FIND_IN_SET and i tried but it didnt work neither. Im not even sure if it's implemented in slamdata.

Is there any other way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This question was also asked on the SlamData Google Groups user forum [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/slamdata-user/FfR1H23Olqc/zLXXGuzHCwAJ).

To summarize, this approach should work:

> orders.pracownicy[*]=worker._id